# Finding startAngle and arcAngle to pass into drawArc() of Java Graphics

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, oracle-spatial

So I have queries from a database that uses SDO_GEOMETRY to create arcs and they are made using 3 sets of points: (xStart,yStart), (xCenter,yCenter),(xEnd,yEnd)

So just imagine a rainbow and the center point is on the very top (shown as X2,Y2)
[image: Arc example:]
I am now trying to translate this so that I can use drawArc() in Java's Graphics. However drawArc() takes in parameters and I am stuck at the startArc and arcAngle parameters and am not sure how to compute those.

I've looked around and there are also "end angles" or "center angles" of an arc, not sure if those are the same thing and I haven't found a good source on how to compute startArc and arcAngle. Does anyone have familiarity with this? Please share and thanks!

Comment: As an alternative to using `drawArc`, you might consider using a [QuadCurve2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/QuadCurve2D.Double.html) instance - you would have to compute the control point based upon the center point, but that's relatively simple math.

Answer (score 3):

This should help you with your parameter code, you can always plug in your variables as long as theyre int

[image]

helpful links:
http://jdrawing.sourceforge.net/doc/0.2.5/api/org/jdrawing/graphics/DrawArc.html
http://www.java-examples.com/draw-arc-applet-window-example

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using `drawArc` is to use a [QuadCurve2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/QuadCurve2D.Double.html) (although not familiar with your geometry, this approach may be required if the points don't define a symmetric geometry). You would need to calculate the control point for the curve, which can be done using the [Bezier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) equation

```
B(t) = (1-t)^2 * P0 + 2(1-t)tP1 + t^2 P2
```

Here, B(t) is a point on the line. Solving for the Control point:

```
P1 = (B(t) - (1-t)^2 * P0 - t^2 P2)/2(1-t)t
```

For a center point, t = 0.5:

```
//example points, assuming center is at 0.5
int[] p1 = {100,50};
int[] center = {200,100};
int[] p3 = {300,50};
double x = (center[0] - Math.pow(0.5, 2) * p1[0] - Math.pow(0.5, 2) * p3[0] ) / (2*(0.5) * 0.5);
double y = (center[1] - Math.pow(0.5, 2) * p1[1] - Math.pow(0.5, 2) * p3[1] ) / (2*(0.5) * 0.5);
QuadCurve2D curve = new QuadCurve2D.Double(p1[0], p1[1], x, y, p3[0], p3[1]);
g.draw(curve);
```

The above shows the equations explicitly for demonstration, but can be simplified with constants to the `Math.pow` and `denominator`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am stuck at the startArc and arcAngle parameters and am not sure how to compute those.

There are many different ways to specify the two arc parameters.

One way is to use 0 and 180, which means you start at the end point and draw an arc 180 degrees counter clockwise, back to the start point. (ie. from the API documentatation: *Angles are interpreted such that 0 degrees is at the 3 o'clock position. A positive value indicates a counter-clockwise rotation while a negative value indicates a clockwise rotation*)

So I think the general code would be:

```
g.drawArc (x1, y2, x3 - x1, (y2- y1) * 2, 0, 180);
```